# RxJs: ConcatMap VS ConcatMapTo, MergeMap VS MergeMapTo

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

The documentation isn't helpful enough for me to understand the difference between these.

> It's like concatMap, but maps each value always to the same inner
>   Observable.
>   http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/operators/concatMapTo.js.html

I tried checking out learnrxjs.io's examples on stackblitz, but even with those, I wasn't able to immediately identify what the distinguishing feature was separating these.

FYI i saw this other similar question
[What is the difference between mergeMap and mergeMapTo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290306/what-is-the-difference-between-mergemap-and-mergemapto)
but the answer in there wasn't satisfactory, because in the learnrxjs.io examples, they clearly map to observables, not hard-coded values.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmapto.html

If someone could provide some examples (and maybe a brief explanation) to help distinguish the *** vs the ***To higher-order observable operators, I'd appreciate that, thanks.

Comment: [This](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/concepts/get-started-transforming#mapping-to-a-constant-value-with-mapto) explains it beautifully. Summary: sometimes you don't need to use the returned value of an observable. Instead of `map(event => 'You clicked!')`, or `map(() => 'You clicked!')`, you can achieve the same result using `mapTo('You clicked!')`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply said, variants **with** `*To` will always use the same Observable that needs to be created when the whole chain is created regardless of the values emitted by the chain. They take an **Observable** as a parameter.

Variants **without** `*To` can create and return any Observable only when their source Observable emits. They take a **callback** as a parameter.

For example when I use `mergeMapTo` I'm always subscribing to the same Observable:

```
source.pipe(
  mergeMapTo(of(1)),
)
```

Every emission from `source` will always be mapped to `of(1)` and there's no way I can change that.

One the other hand with just `mergeMap` I can return any Observable I want depending on the value received:

```
source.pipe(
  mergeMap(v => of(v * 2)),
)
```

Maybe an easier way to think about this is to remember that `*To` variants map a value to a constant (even when it's not a "real JavaScript constant").

Comment: thanks!  took me a while to understand your answer, but now i get it.  the *To ones take an observable as the direct argument, whereas the ones without the *To suffix take a function as the direct argument (and that function could conditionally return various, different observables depending on given conditional logic).